# Holo Light appearing completely white on HTC One X

Tags: android

Just getting started with Android development, the Holo Light theme is set in my styles.xml for v14. The theme appears correctly on all the emulators (it looks like the screenshot at http://developer.android.com/design/style/themes.html. However when I load it on my HTC One X the ActionBar and the buttons all appear completely white on a white background. I am certain it is using the theme setting from the styles.xml v14 folder. How can this be, I thought Holo themes were supposed to appear the same across all devices? Any suggestions on how to make the Holo light theme appear correctly on my device?